# ABP other tenant users are not visible in retrieve function

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP BOILER PLATE template under MVC5 structure. Here I want to retrieve all the users with their tenant, but It only shows the users who are in the default tenant. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: disable IMayHaveTenantId Filter https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Data-Filters#imayhavetenant